# xcode bots edit failed

Tags: xcode, bots, osx-server

I am running OS X Server(5.0.4) and xcode 7. I am able to crete bots successfully but when I edit an existing bot, xcode throws this error :

> Internal Error Updating Bot, please try configuring the bot again

How do I solve it?

Comment: Formatting. Added osx-server tag

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are connected to the server and logged in to it.

I ran in to this issue when I was connected to the server, but actually wasn't logged in.

You do this in the Preferences panel and just make sure your password is entered.